# Java class keyword

Tags: java, class, methods, static, keyword

I found a few days ago a code in Java that uses the **class** keyword in the context, for example:

```
MyConcreteClass.class.AMethod();
```

I've tried to do it in a JFrame, for example:

```
JFrame.class.getName();
```

And that works but... I can't figure out/find on the internet what this keyword means in that context. I've only used it to declare classes.

Can anyone explain me what **class** means in this context?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this context `class` is not a keyword, it's a special attribute (a "class literal") of a class denoting its corresponding instance of [`Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html). For example, to obtain the `Class` object of `String`, we do this: `String.class`. The value returned is the instance of `Class` that represents `String`'s class (notice the use of upper and lowercase).

Here `.class` is used on the actual class, to obtain the same result using one of its instances we use the `getclass()` method. Continuing with our example, this snippet returns the same instance of `Class` corresponding to a `String`: `"".getClass()`.

To round the idea - this snippet will always return `true`, for any class with a corresponding instance you want to test:

```
"".getClass().equals(String.class)
```

Answer (score 2):

In this context, `class` is part of a [class literal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2) referring to the [Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) object representing that class.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `class` keyword in your example will give you an object instance of the `Class<JFrame>` type.

Answer (score 1):

When you do JFrame.class you are getting a `Class<JFrame>` instance, so you can call the `getName` method.

The class literal allows you access to information about the class in question.