# Difference between className.class.someMethod vs className.this.someMethod in Java?

Tags: java, class, this

What is difference between `className.class.someMethod` and `className.this.someMethod` in Java?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16288156/1743880

Comment: Well `.class` gives you a `Class` reference... whereas `className.this` gives you the containing instance of the appropriate class.

Comment: Could you give me simple example where should I use className.class.someMethod vs className.this.someMethod

Comment: I suggest you actually read what the `Class` class is for in java. And what `this` means. This question is too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two are not related.

`className.class` gives you an instance of the `Class` class, so `className.class.someMethod()` invokes `someMethod` of `Class` class.

`className.this` is used to access the containing (enclosing) instance of an inner class, so `className.this.someMethod()` invokes a method of that containing instance (which belongs to the `className` class.

```
public class A 
{
    public void someMethod () {}

    public class B
    {
        public void someMethod () {}

        public void someOtherMethod ()
        {
            A.this.someMethod (); // invokes someMethod of the class A instance that
                                  // encloses this B instance

            A.class.getName (); // invokes the getName method of the Class class
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: what do you mean that A.class.getName() will invoke the getName method of the Class class? The Class class is confusing me. I would very much appreciate if you could make an example with system.out.print so I can see difference more clearly.

Comment: @MyNameIsNemo There is a class whose name is `Class` (actually the full name is java.lang.Class). That class has a method called `getName()`. You could pass the output of that method to `System.out.print()`, since it returns a String.

Comment: I see, so If I write B.class.someMethod() it will call someMethod() from class A?